El significado de “Celo macho, África ... A mí sino, fiel seré"
Perdonen, quisiera preguntar sobre el significado de “celo macho, '
África” y su relación con "A mí sino, fiel seré" en
“Celo macho, África
Tu abanico se ensangrentará
A mí sino, fiel seré
¿Qué veneno fue?”
¿Por qué se menciona ser fiel después de hablarse de “un celo macho”?
Supongo que “celo macho” se refiere a un hombre que tiene interés extremado y activo que siente por una causa o por una persona.
“África” también significa ábrego, además de poder referirse a africano - viento templado y húmedo del sudoeste, que trae lluvias. Pero no estoy seguro si a este significado se refiere en este caso.
¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda por adelantado!

No olvides que "celo" también significa "apetito sexual", aunque la RAE lo limita a los animales, creo que hace más a referencia a ello, sobre todo por el símil que sigue: "tu abanico se ensangrentará", que podría hacer referencia al sangrado del primer coito. África, si no sé a qué viene. A mi sino, fiel seré, la entiendo como: "No seré fiel sino a mi", o "solo seré fiel a mi".

"Sino" es un sustantivo: Seré fiel a mi sino (= seré fiel a mi destino)

Veamos esta interpretación (ojo que la letra de canciones a menudo es metafórica y está teñida de las vivencias de quien las escribe).
"Celo macho, África": Esto podría referirse a una representación arquetípica de África como un continente lleno de energía, vitalidad, y quizás en este caso, virilidad
"Tu abanico se ensangrentará": La imagen del "abanico" podría simbolizar diversidad o amplitud (como la diversidad cultural, geográfica, y biológica de África). El hecho de que "se ensangrentará" podría aludir a conflictos, violencia o luchas que han ocurrido en la historia del continente.
"A mí sino, fiel seré": "Sino" se refiere al destino o la fortuna. Esta línea podría significar una promesa de ser fiel a su destino o a lo que el destino le depara, lo cual sugiere una aceptación o resignación ante lo inevitable.
"¿Qué veneno fue?": Esta pregunta parece buscar la causa de algún dolor, daño o problema. Podría estar preguntando cuál fue el origen de algún mal o adversidad.

!Muchas gracias!
